# What exactly does mqtt depend on tcp for?

Tags: tcp, mqtt

What exactly does mqtt depend on tcp for? As in can it survive without TCP??
I get the connection oriented protocol and stuff but is there more to the relation between MQTT and TCP??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an application level protocol, MQTT makes some assumptions about the connection it is run over:

1. the state of the connection is well known; if the connection is interrupted/broken, then both sides are notified.
2. the bytes that are written at one end of the connection will arrive at the other end in the same order:

   1. any reordering caused by packet fragmentation within the network is hidden.
   2. any corruption to the bytes is resolved

These features are provided by TCP.